# Cómo puedo hacer que un DataGridView tome este aspecto

Tags: c#, windows-forms

[image: Datagridview que quiero lograr]

Solo quisiera saber como hacer que luzca así sin ningún dato y no de la forma por default (fondo gris), o ¿a caso se esta utilizando una imagen de fondo en vez de personalizar las columnas de algún color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para personalizar las columnas con un determinado color seria algo así:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column5"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
```

Para eliminar los bordes entre filas (para que el color sea continuo):

```
 this.dataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
 this.dataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
 this.dataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
 this.dataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
```

Espero que te sea útil.